# Two fragments are displayed when clicking back

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a main container in xml file in which i will replace the fragments depending on the button clicks.

when Activity opened i am adding fragment1 to the main container with the following code

```
    fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container, homeMainFragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

in HomeMainFragment on click of one button doing the following.

```
   Fragment2 fragment2 = new Fragment2 ();
   fragmentTranasaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment2);
   fragmentTranasaction.addToBackStack(null);
   fragmentTranasaction.commit();
```

in Fragment2 on click of another button moving to Fragment3 using the following code.

```
   FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
   Fragment3 fragment3  = new Fragment3 ();
   transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment3 );
   transaction.commit();
```

now when i click back my UI should show HomeFragment instead it showing home as well as fragment3 merged together.

Just wanted to clear on my requirement.
1.when I am viewing fragment3 and click on back i should actually see the homefragment not fragment2.
2. I am not adding fragment3 to the backstack because one of the button in fragment3 again starts fragment2 which will start fragment3. (same code shown above is used) in this case if I click on back I can see multiple instances of fragment3 which i don't need. Please help to solve this issue.

Edit 2:

These are my observations.
in step 1: container has homefragment.xml
in step 2: container replaced by fragment1..xml
in step 3: container is replaced by fragment3.xml
when i click on back container is being added with homefragment which is of transaparent background thats why fragment 3.is still visible.
is there any way when user clicks back remove the backstack and add homefragment alone?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html#back-fragments

add this ".addToBackStack()" to third's fragment transaction.

Comment: hi Jeeri, Have your problem solved?

Comment: i will let you know @Vivek once i it is working!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you have to do.

```
fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container, homeMainFragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

in HomeMainFragment on click of one button doing the following.

```
Fragment2 fragment2 = new Fragment2 ();
fragmentTranasaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment2);
fragmentTranasaction.addToBackStack().commit();
```

in Fragment2 on click of another button moving to Fragment3 using the following code.

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
Fragment3 fragment3  = new Fragment3 ();
transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment3 );
transaction..addToBackStack().commit();
```

Refer below link for more info.

http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html#back-fragments

According to the documentation,
When there are FragmentTransaction objects on the back stack and the user presses the Back button, the FragmentManager pops the most recent transaction off the back stack and performs the reverse action (such as removing a fragment if the transaction added it).

Hope this helps.

Comment: this is not an answer, because if you press back button while fragment 3 is visible it will bring you back to fragment 2, but author of the questions wanted it to bring to home fragment

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
```

Comment: he presses back button!